# Oracle grouping occurring more than once

Tags: oracle, grouping, dimension

I need a solution on the following

```
Group  Begindate enddate     
a1       1/1/2019   2/1/2019 
a1       2/1/2019   3/1/2019
a2       3/1/2019   3/2/2019
a2       3/2/2019   3/4/2019
a1       3/4/2019   3/5/2019
a1       3/5/2019   4/1/2019
```

In the above, I need to get three groups based on the occurrence. 
a1 appeared first followed by a2 followed by a1. 
My result should be like this:

```
group  min(begindate)
a1      1/1/2019
a2       3/1/2019
a1       3/4/2019
```

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This is a [gaps and islands](https://bertwagner.com/2019/03/12/gaps-and-islands/) problem.

```
SELECT group_id,MIN(begindate)
FROM ( SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order BY begindate
       ) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY group_id
            ORDER BY begindate
       ) AS seq
       FROM t
     )
GROUP BY group_id,seq
ORDER BY 2
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=904701baa3e2c64f1525f3e08cf84710)